# how to aggregate multiple rows only different with permutation

Tags: r

how to aggregate multiple rows only different with permutation?

Say. data in data.frame like this:

```
V1, V2
1, 2
3, 2
2, 1
5, 1
7, 8
1, 9
5, 1
```

`1, 2` and `2, 1` should treated as same row. So there are two `1, 2`.

expected result should like:

```
V1, V2, V3
1, 2, 2
3, 2, 1
5, 1, 2
7, 8, 1
1, 9, 1
```

Many solutions I searched only aggregated one column based on another. 
So Those solutions can aggregate `5, 1` as `5, 2`.

And `unique` can not aggregate `1, 2` and `2, 1` either.

No solution found for my expected result. Any reference and advises?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility using `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(grp = paste(exec(pmax, !!!.), exec(pmin, !!!.), sep = "_")) %>%
 add_count(grp, name = "V3") %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp)

     V1    V2    V3
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     2     2
2     3     2     1
3     5     1     2
4     7     8     1
5     1     9     1
```

Or with just `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(grp = paste(pmax(V1, V2), pmin(V1, V2), sep = "_")) %>%
 add_count(grp, name = "V3") %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp)
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(grp = paste(sort(c(V1, V2)), collapse = "_")) %>%
 group_by(grp) %>%
 add_count(grp, name = "V3") %>%
 slice(1) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-grp)
```

Using the same logic with `base R`:

```
df$grp <- with(df, paste(pmax(V1, V2), pmin(V1, V2), sep = "_"))
df$V3 <- with(df, ave(grp, grp, FUN = length))
df <- df[!duplicated(df$grp), ][, -3]
```

Comment: I am installing `dplyr` now. It seems a big package. Is there a simple way? Does `aggregate` work for this?

Comment: Please see the updated post with a `base R` possibility.

Answer (score 0):

An option using `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(V3 = rep(1, nrow(df1)))~., data =  t(apply(df1, 1, sort)), sum)
```